# How to calculate distance between two dihedral (periodic) angles distributions in python?

Tags: python-3.x, distance, distribution, metrics, periodicity

I am searching for the correct and most straightforward way of handling periodicity when calculating the Earth Mover's Distance (EMD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) (also known as Wasserstein metric) between two distributions of dihedral angles.

The range of the dihedrals I get is [-180, 180] according to IUPAC dihedral angles definition.

**I am not sure how to modify my input so that the EMD/Wasserstein will make sense. I feel like I can calculate the EMD on several different modified input and select the minimum, to avoid the periodic boundary issue. Could you please suggest any ideas ?**

Here are some exemples of the inputs I have. For each of them, I want to use a single procedure that gets me the real, minimal EMD distance between
pairwise distributions.

Thank you in advance for any input you may bring :)

**Here is the code I'm currently using**

```
from pyemd import emd
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

bw = 2 # bandwidth used to prepare the data (Y1 .. Yn)

# Wasserstein distance that is independent of bandwidth choice but does not actually work with frequencies ?
wass_dist = bw * wasserstein_distance(Y1, Y2)

# EMD distance that is independent of bandwidth choice but does not take periodic boundaries into account
bins_dihedrals_reshape = np.array(X).reshape(-1,1)
bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix = cdist(bins_dihedrals_reshape, bins_dihedrals_reshape)
emd_dist = bw * emd(Y1, Y2, bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix)
```

**Exemple: Compare BLUE and ORANGE (Y1 and Y2)**

[image: Exemple 1]

```
X= [-179.0,-177.0,-175.0,-173.0,-171.0,-169.0,-167.0,-165.0,-163.0,-161.0,-159.0,-157.0,-155.0,-153.0,-151.0,-149.0,-147.0,-145.0,-143.0,-141.0,-139.0,-137.0,-135.0,-133.0,-131.0,-129.0,-127.0,-125.0,-123.0,-121.0,-119.0,-117.0,-115.0,-113.0,-111.0,-109.0,-107.0,-105.0,-103.0,-101.0,-99.0,-97.0,-95.0,-93.0,-91.0,-89.0,-87.0,-85.0,-83.0,-81.0,-79.0,-77.0,-75.0,-73.0,-71.0,-69.0,-67.0,-65.0,-63.0,-61.0,-59.0,-57.0,-55.0,-53.0,-51.0,-49.0,-47.0,-45.0,-43.0,-41.0,-39.0,-37.0,-35.0,-33.0,-31.0,-29.0,-27.0,-25.0,-23.0,-21.0,-19.0,-17.0,-15.0,-13.0,-11.0,-9.0,-7.0,-5.0,-3.0,-1.0,1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,9.0,11.0,13.0,15.0,17.0,19.0,21.0,23.0,25.0,27.0,29.0,31.0,33.0,35.0,37.0,39.0,41.0,43.0,45.0,47.0,49.0,51.0,53.0,55.0,57.0,59.0,61.0,63.0,65.0,67.0,69.0,71.0,73.0,75.0,77.0,79.0,81.0,83.0,85.0,87.0,89.0,91.0,93.0,95.0,97.0,99.0,101.0,103.0,105.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,117.0,119.0,121.0,123.0,125.0,127.0,129.0,131.0,133.0,135.0,137.0,139.0,141.0,143.0,145.0,147.0,149.0,151.0,153.0,155.0,157.0,159.0,161.0,163.0,165.0,167.0,169.0,171.0,173.0,175.0,177.0,179.0]
Y1= [0.00639872025594881,0.006998600279944011,0.010597880423915218,0.011097780443911218,0.015096980603879224,0.017096580683863227,0.021195760847830435,0.021695660867826434,0.02449510097980404,0.021495700859828035,0.01999600079984003,0.022895420915816835,0.01879624075184963,0.016996600679864027,0.015396920615876825,0.016896620675864827,0.013897220555888823,0.009998000399920015,0.008298340331933614,0.00599880023995201,0.004499100179964007,0.0028994201159768048,0.0016996600679864027,0.0008998200359928015,0.0005998800239952009,0.0003999200159968006,0.0,0.0,0.0001999600079984003,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,9.998000399920016e-05,0.0001999600079984003,0.00029994001199760045,0.0006998600279944011,0.001299740051989602,0.0023995200959808036,0.001999600079984003,0.0034993001399720057,0.0030993801239752048,0.006998600279944011,0.00629874025194961,0.007798440311937612,0.008798240351929614,0.009898020395920816,0.011297740451909618,0.01269746050789842,0.011897620475904818,0.015596880623875225,0.01269746050789842,0.009398120375924815,0.010497900419916016,0.009498100379924015,0.008098380323935212,0.007298540291941612,0.008098380323935212,0.006898620275944811,0.00609878024395121]
Y2= [0.006998600279944011,0.007198560287942412,0.007598480303939212,0.009398120375924815,0.009798040391921616,0.010997800439912017,0.011197760447910418,0.01289742051589682,0.013697260547890422,0.015396920615876825,0.01259748050389922,0.010797840431913617,0.010497900419916016,0.009898020395920816,0.008198360327934412,0.007098580283943211,0.007198560287942412,0.0057988402319536095,0.004599080183963208,0.002999400119976005,0.001899620075984803,0.0016996600679864027,0.0008998200359928015,0.0006998600279944011,0.0005998800239952009,0.0003999200159968006,0.00029994001199760045,9.998000399920016e-05,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,9.998000399920016e-05,0.0,9.998000399920016e-05,9.998000399920016e-05,0.00029994001199760045,0.0001999600079984003,0.0004999000199960008,0.0009998000399920016,0.0015996800639872025,0.0021995600879824036,0.0030993801239752048,0.005298940211957609,0.008698260347930415,0.008998200359928014,0.011397720455908818,0.013197360527894421,0.014997000599880024,0.022295540891821636,0.021795640871825634,0.023495300939812037,0.01969606078784243,0.022695460907818436,0.022395520895820836,0.021595680863827234,0.016596680663867228,0.016796640671865627,0.016196760647870425,0.011897620475904818,0.010697860427914417,0.010597880423915218]
```

Comment: could you expand on what your dataset and application is so that I can understand the meaning behind "periodicity" and "dihedral" better, in an actual intuitive context

Comment: In chemistry, a dihedral angle (or torsion) is this: https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/foldit/images/8/89/Dihedral.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340?cb=20180127045632 or this: https://furmanchm120.pbworks.com/f/1255643135/2-butene_Dihedral.gif. It is the angle between the 2 planes that can be defined from 4 points in a 3D space. Then this dihedral angle domain is [0°, 360°] or more often expressed within [-180°, 180°], and it is therefore periodic.

Comment: I notice you're using `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance`. Do you know how to extract the distance matrix and transport matrix from this function? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131318/how-to-extract-the-distance-and-transport-matrices-from-scipys-wasserstein-dist

Comment: It's not possible with scipy's wasserstein_distance apparently. You can get the OT matrix using other packages such as https://github.com/wmayner/pyemd. Then the distance matrix is an input required for the EMD calculation, not an output (the matrix of distances between bins of one distribution and another is used to solve the OT problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this works. I use pyemd and created a periodic distance matrix.

```
from pyemd import emd
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

X= [-179.0,-177.0,-175.0,-173.0,-171.0,-169.0,-167.0,-165.0,-163.0,-161.0,-159.0,-157.0,-155.0,-153.0,-151.0,-149.0,-147.0,-145.0,-143.0,-141.0,-139.0,-137.0,-135.0,-133.0,-131.0,-129.0,-127.0,-125.0,-123.0,-121.0,-119.0,-117.0,-115.0,-113.0,-111.0,-109.0,-107.0,-105.0,-103.0,-101.0,-99.0,-97.0,-95.0,-93.0,-91.0,-89.0,-87.0,-85.0,-83.0,-81.0,-79.0,-77.0,-75.0,-73.0,-71.0,-69.0,-67.0,-65.0,-63.0,-61.0,-59.0,-57.0,-55.0,-53.0,-51.0,-49.0,-47.0,-45.0,-43.0,-41.0,-39.0,-37.0,-35.0,-33.0,-31.0,-29.0,-27.0,-25.0,-23.0,-21.0,-19.0,-17.0,-15.0,-13.0,-11.0,-9.0,-7.0,-5.0,-3.0,-1.0,1.0,3.0,5.0,7.0,9.0,11.0,13.0,15.0,17.0,19.0,21.0,23.0,25.0,27.0,29.0,31.0,33.0,35.0,37.0,39.0,41.0,43.0,45.0,47.0,49.0,51.0,53.0,55.0,57.0,59.0,61.0,63.0,65.0,67.0,69.0,71.0,73.0,75.0,77.0,79.0,81.0,83.0,85.0,87.0,89.0,91.0,93.0,95.0,97.0,99.0,101.0,103.0,105.0,107.0,109.0,111.0,113.0,115.0,117.0,119.0,121.0,123.0,125.0,127.0,129.0,131.0,133.0,135.0,137.0,139.0,141.0,143.0,145.0,147.0,149.0,151.0,153.0,155.0,157.0,159.0,161.0,163.0,165.0,167.0,169.0,171.0,173.0,175.0,177.0,179.0]
Y1= [0.00639872025594881,0.006998600279944011,0.010597880423915218,0.011097780443911218,0.015096980603879224,0.017096580683863227,0.021195760847830435,0.021695660867826434,0.02449510097980404,0.021495700859828035,0.01999600079984003,0.022895420915816835,0.01879624075184963,0.016996600679864027,0.015396920615876825,0.016896620675864827,0.013897220555888823,0.009998000399920015,0.008298340331933614,0.00599880023995201,0.004499100179964007,0.0028994201159768048,0.0016996600679864027,0.0008998200359928015,0.0005998800239952009,0.0003999200159968006,0.0,0.0,0.0001999600079984003,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,9.998000399920016e-05,0.0001999600079984003,0.00029994001199760045,0.0006998600279944011,0.001299740051989602,0.0023995200959808036,0.001999600079984003,0.0034993001399720057,0.0030993801239752048,0.006998600279944011,0.00629874025194961,0.007798440311937612,0.008798240351929614,0.009898020395920816,0.011297740451909618,0.01269746050789842,0.011897620475904818,0.015596880623875225,0.01269746050789842,0.009398120375924815,0.010497900419916016,0.009498100379924015,0.008098380323935212,0.007298540291941612,0.008098380323935212,0.006898620275944811,0.00609878024395121]
Y2= [0.006998600279944011,0.007198560287942412,0.007598480303939212,0.009398120375924815,0.009798040391921616,0.010997800439912017,0.011197760447910418,0.01289742051589682,0.013697260547890422,0.015396920615876825,0.01259748050389922,0.010797840431913617,0.010497900419916016,0.009898020395920816,0.008198360327934412,0.007098580283943211,0.007198560287942412,0.0057988402319536095,0.004599080183963208,0.002999400119976005,0.001899620075984803,0.0016996600679864027,0.0008998200359928015,0.0006998600279944011,0.0005998800239952009,0.0003999200159968006,0.00029994001199760045,9.998000399920016e-05,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,9.998000399920016e-05,0.0,9.998000399920016e-05,9.998000399920016e-05,0.00029994001199760045,0.0001999600079984003,0.0004999000199960008,0.0009998000399920016,0.0015996800639872025,0.0021995600879824036,0.0030993801239752048,0.005298940211957609,0.008698260347930415,0.008998200359928014,0.011397720455908818,0.013197360527894421,0.014997000599880024,0.022295540891821636,0.021795640871825634,0.023495300939812037,0.01969606078784243,0.022695460907818436,0.022395520895820836,0.021595680863827234,0.016596680663867228,0.016796640671865627,0.016196760647870425,0.011897620475904818,0.010697860427914417,0.010597880423915218]

bw = 2 # bandwidth used to prepare the data (Y1 .. Yn)
bins_dihedrals = np.arange(-180, 180+bw_dihedrals, bw_dihedrals)
bins_dihedrals_reshape = np.array(bins_dihedrals).reshape(-1,1)
bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix = cdist(bins_dihedrals_reshape, bins_dihedrals_reshape) # 'classical' distance matrix
bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix_periodoc = np.where(bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix > max(bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix[0])/2, max(bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix[0])-bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix, bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix) # modify distance matrix for periodicity

emd_dist = bw * emd(Y1, Y2, bins_dihedrals_dist_matrix_periodic)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html

From the description of the function given on the page above:

> `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance(u_values, v_values, u_weights=None, v_weights=None)`:
>
> Compute the first Wasserstein distance between two 1D distributions.
>
> This distance is also known as the **earth mover’s distance** since it
>   can be seen as the minimum amount of “work” required to transform *u*
>   into *v*, where “work” is measured as the amount of distribution
>   weight that must be moved, multiplied by the distance it has to be
>   moved.

Comment: Thank you. It is true that I can use scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance, so that potential users of my code will have 1 less dependency to install (pyemd) because scipy is mainstream (edited my question). However, I am more interested into (1) how can Wasserstein could be applied to periodic data and (2) how I could transform my data so that periodicity is handled properly for this case of dihedral angles comparison.