# How to extract the distance and transport matrices from Scipy's wasserstein_distance?

Tags: python, statistics, probability-density, transport, scipy.stats

The `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` function only returns the minimum distance (the solution) between two input distributions, `p` and `q`. But that distance is the result of the product of a distance matrix and an optimal transport matrix that must have been computed inside the same function.

How can I extract the distance matrix and optimal transport matrix that correspond to the solution as 2nd and 3rd output arguments?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that you can get the calculated transport matrix from scipy's wasserstein_distance. You can get it via other packages though, like https://github.com/wmayner/pyemd. I have been using this package for a while and it works pretty fine, while also executing very quickly. Look into the function emd_with_flow() within section Usage.

Then the distance matrix is an input of the EMD calculation, not an output.

Comment: I'm also aware of another package, `pot`, but the question here is about scipy, which I know is intended for 1D source and target distributions, which is all  my application needs. Looking at the scipy code, I found that the `wasserstein_distance` calls another, more general, function which doesn't even calculate the transport matrix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131513/transport-matrix-is-missing-in-the-code-behind-scipy-stats-wasserstein-distance