# Transport matrix is missing in the code behind scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance

Tags: python, matrix, distance, transport, scipy.stats

Looking at the [comments for the code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/aa8ebbc3fc0e8057ae2cbd3255a702dd8f0ab94d/scipy/stats/stats.py#L7887) behind `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` which invokes a function called `_cdf_distance(p, u_values, v_values, u_weights=None, v_weights=None)`, it says this function implements the following formula:

`l_p(u, v) = \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |U-V|^p \right)^{1/p}`

However, this is *not* the Wasserstein distance as I know it since, although I see the **distance matrix** `|U-V|` in the above formula comment, the **transport matrix** is noticeably absent. The transport matrix is supposed to be multiplied against the distance matrix within the integral.

Why is the transport matrix missing from `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance`?

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand the **scipy** Wasserstein distance for this reason. Where is the cost matrix?

You can use my package [**pykantorovich**](https://pykantorovich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it allows to specify a cost matrix. Here is an example using rational numbers so the result is exact.

```py
from pykantorovich.kantorovich import kantorovich
import numpy as np
mu = ['1/7','2/7','4/7']
nu = ['1/4','1/4','1/2']
d = np.array([
  ['0', '1', '2'],
  ['1', '0', '1'],
  ['2', '1', '0']
], dtype = "f")
kantorovich(mu, nu, distance_matrix=d)
```

result:

```
{
 distance: 5/28
 joining:
 [['1/7' '0' '0']
 ['1/28' '1/4' '0']
 ['1/14' '0' '1/2']]
 optimal: yes
}
```

Note: Kantorovich distance = Wasserstein distance. This distance has a dozen of names.